# Mongoose: match: {date} query is not returning data in production environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using this fuction to retrieve populated appointments on a certain date:

```
router.post('/event/specific/practitioner', function(req, res){      
    var today = moment(req.body.today).startOf('day').format();
    var todayStart = moment(req.body.today).startOf('day').toString();
    var todayEnd = moment(req.body.today).endOf('day').subtract(1, 'hours').toString();

    console.log(today);
    console.log(todayStart);
    console.log(todayEnd);

    Practitioner.find()         
    .populate({path: 'appointments', match: { date: {"$gte": todayStart, "$lt": todayEnd }}, populate: [{path: 'customer', model: 'Customer'}, {path: 'bills', model: 'Bill'}, {path: 'practitioner', model: 'Practitioner'}]})        
    .exec(function(err, practitioners){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Oeps! Er ging iets mis met het ophalen van de afspraken.' });
        }else{
            console.log(practitioners);
            res.json({ success: true, practitioners: practitioners });   
        }
    })
})
```

On my localhost it does return the three appointments that match the date. However, when I perform the same query in my live environment (mlab + Heroku) this same query returns an empty array of appointments for the same date.

**Result from the console logs on local:**

2019-01-14T00:00:00+01:00

Mon Jan 14 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100

Mon Jan 14 2019 22:59:59 GMT+0100

**Result from the console logs on live:**

2019-01-14T00:00:00+00:00

Mon Jan 14 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0000

Mon Jan 14 2019 22:59:59 GMT+0000

Comment: Your local and production are not in the same timezone. Maybe your three appointments are at the beginning or the end of the day?

Comment: How can I avoid this? Should I store all the dates as strings?